# Changing Static IP in Azure VM (Ubuntu OS)

Tags: azure

Is it possible to change the static IP provisioned with a classic VM (Ubuntu OS)? If so, could you please provide the steps of how to do so?

I recently deployed CloudFlare with my infrastructure, primarily for DDOS prevention. One of the requirements is changing the server IP so that malicious vectors who know the server IP can't just bypass CloudFlare and DDOS my infrastructure. I'm using a static IP; how do I change that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IP addresses in Azure fall into two categories: dynamic and reserved. Public IP addresses managed by Azure are dynamic by default.

> Is it possible to change the static IP provisioned with a classic VM
>   (Ubuntu OS)?

Yes, we can use PowerShell to set/remove/add **reserved VIP** for Azure classic VM.

Reserved IP address  can be used only as a VIP, ensuring that the IP address for the cloud service remains the same, even as resources are shut down or stopped (deallocated).

`New-AzureReservedIP –ReservedIPName MyReservedIP –Location "Central US"
Get-AzureReservedIP
set-AzureReservedIPAssociation -ReservedIPName MyReservedIP -ServiceName TestService`

More information about reserved IP address, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-reserved-public-ip).

Comment: Thanks Jason. Moreover, what's the downtime window I need to be aware of? I need to ensure service disruption is minimized for the sake of my users.

Comment: When we set reserved IP address, we will **lost** connection,  after the reserved IP address set complete, we can use new IP address to login this VM, the VM no need to reboot.